# align radiobutton inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a div ,and inside div there is radio buttons, what is the easiest way to align radio button according to text vertically in same line inside div

```
echo"<div  id=\"div{$id}\" ";?> 
                    echo"</br>

                    <input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option1}\" >
                    $option1
                    </br>

                    <input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option2}\">
                     $option2
                    </br>

                    <input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option3}\">
                    $option3
                    </br>

                    <input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option4}\">
                     $option4

                    </br></br>";
                    echo"</div>";
```

in above code values are taken from db, I want to know how to align radiobuttons inside div vertically in same line.

Comment: You should wrap `type` attributes' value `radio` in quotes, and write `</br>` as `<br/>` since it is an empty tag.

Comment: Write _proper_ HTML code - put your radio buttons into labels, then formatting them should be no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style radio buttons like this:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    margin-top: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much,i am just a beginner!, where should i write this?,in head section inside style tag,or as inline style code??plz help me

Comment: @sarincm99 You could add this to your style sheet (whether linked or in the page), or you can inline the style properties directly in the inputs like this: `<input type="radio" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-top: 0" name=...`.

Answer (score -4):

You could try it with a table:

```
echo"<div  id=\"div{$id}\" ";?> 

echo"<br />
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option1}\" >
</td>
<td>
$option1
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option2}\" >
</td>
<td>
$option2
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option3}\" >
</td>
<td>
$option3
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option4}\" >
</td>
<td>
$option4
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</br></br>";

echo"</div>";
```

Comment: thank you for help,after applying it radio button is alligned,but another problem arise,i am using div which will hide after clicking next then next div appear,but now div is not hiding,is there any problem using table inside div?plz help me...

Answer (score -5):

you will have to put them in the table for proper alignment...

```
echo"<div  id=\"div{$id}\" ";?> 
                echo"</br>
<table><tr>
                <td align=cente valign=middle><input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option1}\" ></td><td align=center valign=middle>
                $option1</td></tr>

                <td align=cente valign=middle><input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option2}\"></td></td><td align=center valign=middle>
                 $option2</td></tr>
                </br>

                <td align=cente valign=middle><input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option3}\"></td><td align=center valign=middle>
                $option3</td></tr>
                </br>

                <td align=cente valign=middle><input type= radio name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option4}\"></td><td align=center valign=middle>
                 $option4</td></tr>
```

";
                        echo"";